# Define State type on react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm calling a movie API, and want the searchValue to be updated everytime I write in the search bar. However, it seems like I need to define the "setSearchValue" as I'm using typescript. How can I do it?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import MovieList from './components/MovieList'
import Search from './components/Search';


const App: React.FC = () => {

    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

    const getMovieRequest = async () => {
        const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchValue}&apikey=520a7faf`;

        const response = await fetch(url);
        const responseJson = await response.json();

        if(responseJson.Search) {
            setMovies(responseJson.Search);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getMovieRequest(searchValue);
    }, [searchValue]);

    console.log(movies);

    return (
        <>
            <Search searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
            <ScrollView>
                <MovieList movies={movies} />
            </ScrollView>

        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

And here is the Search component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

interface Props {
    value: string;
    searchValue: string;
}

const Search: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    return (
       <View>
           <TextInput 
           placeholder="Search here"
           value={props.value}
           onChange={(event) => props.setSearchValue(event.target.value)}
           />
       </View>
    );
}

export default Search;
```

I'm getting the error: "Property 'setSearchValue' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren'."

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the interface declaration.

Replace below code:

```
interface Props {
    value: string;
    searchValue: string;
}
```

With the New Code:

```
interface Props {
    searchValue: string;
    setSearchValue:(searchVal: string) => void;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>' is not assignable to type '() => void'.

Comment: make changes by adding param in the interface I have updated the code please check it out.